# mysqlimport Error 1064

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a simple CSV File via mysqlimport and got the following error:

```
mysqlimport '--fields-enclosed-by="' '--fields-terminated-by=;' '--lines-terminated-by=\n' '--columns=Name;Vorname;Test' -u db01usr -pPW01 db01 /var/www/vhosts/path/httpdocs/feedtest/test.csv
```

Error:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';Vorname;Test)' at line 1, when using table: test
```

The file is:

```
Name;Vorname;Test
Test1;Test2;Test3
```

The mySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` text,
  `Vorname` text,
  `Test` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `,` instead of semicolon to separate the columns:

```
mysqlimport '--fields-enclosed-by="' \
            '--fields-terminated-by=;' \
            '--lines-terminated-by=\n' \
            '--columns=Name,Vorname,Test' \
            -u db01usr -pPW01 db01 /var/www/vhosts/path/httpdocs/feedtest/test.csv
```